# Is it possible to kasher black stainless steel sinks?

Tags: kashering-kosherization

Is it possible to kasher a "black stainless steel" sink?

I mean not one that is painted but one that is made with black metal coating, like jewelry.

[Example](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Glacier-Bay-Gunmetal-Black-Stainless-Steel-27-in-18-Gauge-Single-Bowl-Undermount-Kitchen-Sink-ACS2718A1/316946092)

Comment: What is the coating made of? Does it have the Halachic status of glass or the status of earthenware?

Comment: The Home Depot link states that it is PVD (physical vapor deposition) coated. The [CRC lists PVD](https://consumer.crckosher.org/consumer/kashering/) as a material that can be kashered.

Comment: Google says it's a polymer based paint coating.

Comment: PVD might be made with Titanium Nitrade, a ceramic. You would need to know more about the product and the process to get a clear answer.